# Replacing URL with part of that URL in Big Query

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I'm trying to write SQL in big query to replace strings below with middle part of the string

`sports.xxxx.com/en-gb/betting/football/vasdas`

`sports.xxxx.com/en-gb/betting/basketball/blablabla`

`sports.xxxx.com/en-gb/betting/football/`

`sports.xxxx.com/en-gb/betting/golf`

So result would be

`football`

`basketball`

`football`

`golf`

I tried to use
`SELECT 
REGEXP_REPLACE('sports.xxxx.com/en-gb/betting/football', '.*', '(?<=\b\/betting\/)(\w+)')`

but I get an error `Error: Invalid string literal: '(?<=\b\/betting\/)(\w+)'`
Any ideas how I can make it?

Comment: Try `SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('sports.ladbrokes.com/en-gb/betting/football', r'(?<=\b/betting/)\w+')`

Comment: `Error: Failed to parse regular expression "(?<=\b/betting/)\w‌​+": invalid perl operator: (?<`

Comment: Ok, so, you need a capturing group with `REGEX_EXTRACT`: `SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('spor‌​ts.ladbrokes.com/en-g‌​b/betting/football', r'\b/betting/(\w‌​+)')`

Comment: It works, thanks so much!

Comment: Great, I posted an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the single backslashes you used in the string literal that formed invalid escape sequences.

You need a capturing group with [**`REGEX_EXTRACT`**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regexp_extract):

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('spor‌​‌​ts.ladbrokes.com/en‌​-g‌​b/betting/footbal‌​l', r'\b/betting/(\w‌​+)‌​')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gG3yE4/1)

Note also that Big Query regex syntax is powered by the RE2 regex library that does not support lookarounds at all (and you tried to use a positive loobehind `(?<=....)`).

The pattern details:

- `\b` - a word boundary (trailing). It might be unnecessary, you may remove it safely
- `/betting/` - a literal substring `/betting/` (note the forward slashes are not special for regex, they need no escaping)
- `(\w‌​+)‌` - Group 1, the part of the string that will be returned by the `REGEX_EXTRACT`, capturing 1 or more word chars (letters, digits or underscores).

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expression is extremely powerful yet expensive feature
If you have option to avoid using it in favor of using cheaper functions  - you at least should try

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(url, 1 + LENGTH('sports.xxxx.com/en-gb/betting/'), 
         INSTR(REPLACE(url + '/', 'sports.xxxx.com/en-gb/betting/', ''), '/') - 1 
  ) as sport
FROM 
(SELECT 'sports.xxxx.com/en-gb/betting/football/vasdas' AS url),
(SELECT 'sports.xxxx.com/en-gb/betting/basketball/blablabla' AS url),
(SELECT 'sports.xxxx.com/en-gb/betting/football/' AS url),
(SELECT 'sports.xxxx.com/en-gb/betting/golf' AS url)
```

When processing massive amount of rows, above approach can save you from errors like Resource exceeded or Timeout , etc. (of course depends on actual query you have that above is part of). Also you should always keep your eyes on Billing Tier - that potentially can be higher for expensive queries with regexp